# Different notebook output

Tags: jupyter-notebook

This is my first notebook.

Here is the screenshot[image]

In the frontend however, I am not getting the desired output:. 
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/analytics/notebooks/v2/26c7b6df-fabb-43b6-9060-c41d1f04799b/view?access_token=2d1c7c84b9d6076c25178cf171bc7a40d1b558d6105f3afd88a464d1c4e05651

Here is the screenshot:

[image]!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the issue is resolved after opting for Save Version under File menu.